# How can I make heads in minecraft have specific players skins?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Are there any commands that allow you to use a player's skin on the default heads in Minecraft?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203836/ho-to-get-minecraft-heads-from-a-specific-player-skin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/give username minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"Notch"}
```

Replace the "username" with the player you wish to give the head to (i.e. yourself). Then replace the "Notch" with the player whose skin you would like on that head.

This will work on PC Minecraft 1.7+