# How do I get minecraft heads from a specific player skin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to get the head of a skin which you can find on planet Minecraft? I do not know any players who use that particular skin, so I have no clue about how to get that specific head.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203791/how-can-i-make-heads-in-minecraft-have-specific-players-skins

Answer (score 1):

With the 1.8 update, [how player head items store the skin has changed](http://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftHeads/comments/251m9d/discussion_dinnerbone_changed_the_way_heads_work/) so that it remembers the skin *when the head was created* instead of updating anytime the player updates their skin.

This means that you can pick a skin from anywhere, wear it temporarily, give yourself your own head with the command `/give @p skull <amount> 3 {SkullOwner:"<yourUserName>"}` (replace `<amount>` and `<yourUserName>` as appropriate), and then change your skin back to your normal skin. The head in your inventory will always have the skin you were wearing when you created it.

Dinnerbone explained this new feature:

> When you place a skull with a players name in vanilla, it looks up their skin as it at that moment and saves that information in the NBT. If that player then changes their name... nothing happens to the skull, it already knows which skin it wants to show and it's going to stay on that skin for all of time.
>
> You can just change your players skin to a silly clown, generate that skull and change your skin back to normal. That skull will always look the way you just made it look, the worlds silliest clown. Go copy that nbt tag and share it on reddit or with friends or print it out and slap it on the walls of streets, anyone who makes the same skull/item with the same nbt tag will have a skull with that silly clown head

Comment: The @p should be `<player>` where `<player>` is the player to receive the head. And skull should be `minecraft:skull` just for compliance and consistency sake. For example `/give ydobonebi minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:DinnerBone}` Also note the quotes are not required.

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

1. Download skin from planetminecraft
2. Set downloaded skin as your own
3. Go into the game and make a head of yourself --> There you go!

Comment: And if I change my skin again, will the head change or stay the same?

Comment: @armzngunz it will change

Comment: @xornob Not anymore! As of 1.8 it doesn't change.

Answer (score -2):

You can get other players heads by simply typing in a plyers username where skull owner is. It is not necessary to change our skin.