# Duplicating heads in Creative doesn't work on Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I would look at a head (in Minecraft Creative), then I would press <kbd>command</kbd> + "button 3" and it would give me a Steve Head with "+ NBT" at the bottom. I heard if it shows "+ NBT" at the bottom, it has worked, but my head was still Steve.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure with there's a bug with using pick block on heads. See if this works: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/204104/118457

Comment: Are you looking at a Steve Head?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's a bug, which you can read about here:

http://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-86138

Comment: Do you have any proof? Is there a bug tracker on mojang about this?

Comment: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-86138

Comment: adding that to the answer can be a better choice